# Get Boolean Value for each line of a list from xpath response using scrapy

Tags: python, list, xpath, scrapy

While using `scrapy`, I have an `xpath` response which returns a list. I would like to check for each line of the list whether it contains a string or not. So the result should be a list of booleans.

How is that done using `scrapy` and `response.xpath`?

This is my Workaround:
Since scrapy is using XPath 1, I had to build a workaround because in Xpath 1 every node is unique. As a result Xpath 1 can return each heading only once. This is what I did to solve the problem:

Problem:


Heading 1 

Text 1 

Text 2

Text 3

Heading 2

Text 4

Text 5

Text 6

Result:

True

True

What I wanted to receive something like this:

True

True

False

True

True

False

So instead of using Xpath selectors to retrieve the boolean values, I used scrapy to retrieve the full page source code. Then, I iterated over this string according to my needs using standard python string operations and loops. Main problem was that Xpath 1 can return each node only once.

Comment: What is the input, desired output and what have you already done?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if each list item contains a string, then you can use the other approach.

If you consider the below sample html, find out the list items which does not have `fruit` in list item text.

```html
<html>
  <div class="navbar navbar-blue"> 
    <select>
  <option> Apple fruit</option>
  <option> fruit kiwi </option>
  <option> this should not select</option>
  <option> citrus fruit</option>
 </select>
</div>
</html>
```

You can get the list items that does not contains the string using the below xpath.

```
//select/option[not(contains(.,'fruit'))]
```

[image]